# Why is the AWS Dynamo SDK's getItem method executing my callback function multiple times?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following code that uses the AWS SDK for Node to hit DynamoDB:

```
var aws = require('./aws')

...

var key = "fookey";

aws.dynamo.getItem({
    "TableName": "TableFoo",
    "Key": {
        "FooKey": {
            "S": key
        }
    }
}, function(error, data) {
    if(err != null) {
        callback(500);
    }
    else if(data.Item != null) {
        var obj = { values: [] };
        callback(null, obj);
    }
    else {
        callback(null, data.Item.values.S);
    }
});
```

What's happening is that the call successfully executes and the expected result is returned.  BUT - then - the callback function is executed a second time and the error object is set to:

```
{ [SyntaxError: Unexpected token o] statusCode: 200, retryable: false }
```

Any idea why this is happening?  This is with the latest version of the AWS SDK for Node.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly it looks like this happens when you are calling this code from a unit test and an assert in that test fails.  I'm going to speak with Amazon about this.

Comment: what was your problem?  Could it be provisioned capacity? IE the result was not JSON.parse-able?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misspelled the error variable at the first if conditional expression. You wrote err instead of error.

```
function(error, data) {
    if(err != null) {    <-- // err should be error
        callback(500);
    }
```